# LibGDX: Whats the difference between drawing by Sprite and drawing by SpriteBatch?

Tags: java, libgdx

While programming with LibGDX I noticed that there are two methods to draw a sprite. But first of all that is my situation:

```
(...)
SpriteBatch batch;
Sprite testSprite;
(...)
batch = new SpriteBatch();
testSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("test.png"));
(...)
```

The first method is from the SpriteBatch:

```
(...)
batch.draw(testSprite,...);
(...)
```

The second method is from the Sprite itself:

```
(...)
testSprite.draw(batch);
(...)
```

What are the differences between this methods? Hope you can help me :D
~ Henri

PS: I´m beginner :D

Comment: `SpriteBatch` having no any `draw(...)` method that take `Sprite` as in first argument.

Comment: it extends of TextureRegion

Comment: Ohhh. sorry I forgot who is parent of `Sprite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
testSprite.draw(batch);
```

`Sprite` holds the geometry, color, and texture information for drawing 2D sprites using Batch. A Sprite has a position and a size given as width and height.

In a simple way you can say Sprite is a complete package(where to draw and with different factor like size, scale factor,rotation..).

But If you use

```
batch.draw(testSprite,...);
```

Then you've to instruct position, size and another factor that required for drawing by another argument of `draw(..)` method.

Comment: Thank you, great explanation :D